# What is the reason behind the decline of Indian Physics?

Tags: ancient-india, india

As in what were the main factors, personalities, policies, etc involved in its decline  during the $16^{th}$ century to the present day?

Comment: What do you mean with " Indian Physics" ? The term "physics" in the modern sense started to be used in Europe in 19th Century.

Comment: Not to refute alleged trends with anecdotes, but; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyendra_Nath_Bose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subrahmanyan_Chandrasekhar

Comment: I am somewhat baffled by the premise, insofar as there have been many (very good) Indian physicists in the 20th century, etc.

Comment: I do not know about "decline", but Wikipedia has a dedicated article [History of science and technology in the Indian subcontinent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_science_and_technology_in_the_Indian_subcontinent) with a long reference list to authoritative sources.

Comment: To speak of decline, it had to stand high first of all at some moment. Can you list any achievements of Indian physics before 16 century?

Comment: Close as unclear what you're asking and/or primarily opinion-based

Comment: This seems to be a restatement of the Needham question.